# Call a perl script from another perl script with specific user authentication

Tags: perl, session

I have a system script as below to display stack detail

```
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 bin  bin    6560 Feb 17 21:01 displayPD
[sufuser@101 bin]$ ./displayPD

Usage: ./displayPD -n node
```

Note (this script cannot be run as root)

I want to automate and call this in a script, which is also written with same user login.

But when I call it from my script using `system` command as below it is called as a root and script fails to execute. how do I retain user session for execution ?

```
system("/opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf/bin/displayPD -n Node03 >> /tmp/HP_Details.txt");
```

How can I call it as sufuser and get it executed?

Comment: The only way that can happen is if you're running your perl script as root. But the simplest way of running commands as another user is via `su` or `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program is running as root, you can change the real (`$<`) and effective (`$>`) UIDs of the process at will. For your purpose, changing EUID is enough:

```
use v5.12;

say "euid: $>";
system('whoami');
# switch user
$> = 1000; 
say "euid: $>";
system('whoami');
# switch back
$>=$<; 
say "euid: $>";
system('whoami');
```

Running that script as `root`:

```
$ sudo perl uidtest
euid: 0
root
euid: 1000
ben
euid: 0
root
```

Comment: Thanks for the above inputs.